# How to use togglePosition in an accordion using Angular Material 8?

Tags: angular-material2

I am trying to use the `@Input() togglePosition` on an Angular Material Expansion Panel. The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api#MatAccordionTogglePosition) states the following:

> @Input()
>   togglePosition: MatAccordionTogglePosition |
>   The position of the expansion indicator.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-toggleposition-not-working) of me trying to use that Input, but the application fails to build. On the first line of the HTML I have added:

```
<mat-accordion [togglePosition]="'before'">
```

I forked the original example on Angular Material, so I thought it would work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need v8.1.x - your blitz is 8.0.

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to accept your answer If you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `togglePosition` feature was released in v8.1 of Angular Material, so it will not work if you are using v8.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using ' mat-expansion-panel-header ' selector , try to add this code into your styles.css:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  flex-direction: row-reverse !important;
}
```

Since they are using 'flex-direction:row' betwin the toggle arrow and the title , we only have to reverse them